# moving longitudinal window (moving average?)

Tags: matlab, moving-average, longitudinal

I have 12 data points for y and x:-180:30:179. After I plot my data, it looks like a zig-zag pattern and not smooth. To smooth it out, I apply a moving longitudinal window at 30 degrees (i.e., +/-15 deg.). How can I move it forward by one degree at a time, so that the longitudinal window changes like [-15,15], [-14,16], [-13,17], …?

Here is my code so far

```
 %y=data %12datapoint 
 y=[90, 65, 60, 53, 70, 82, 65, 38, 44, 71, 77, 64];
 sum=0;                                                                    
 for x=-180:30:179
    for k=1:30
        sum=sum+y(x-15+k);
    end
    avg(x)=sum/30;
    sum=0;                                                                
  end
```

Comment: Please also include your `y` data and a minimum example of the desired output

Comment: my kind of data points are random. for example my y are y=[79, 65, 60 53, 70, 82, 65, 38, 44, 71, 77, 64]

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? If it's R2016a or newer, you have [`movmean`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movmean.html). Otherwise you can do it using `conv` as explained [here](http://matlabtricks.com/post-11/moving-average-by-convolution).

Comment: Its 2016. Yes thank you for your suggestions. I’ve tried also using conv and filters but thats not what i want. The graph didn’t smooth like I wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be trying to read between the lines to much.  But it sounds like you are not really asking for a moving average.  It kind of sounds like you want your "zig-zag" line smoothed out or [interpolated](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html).  If this is correct you could do something like this:

```
y=[90, 65, 60, 53, 70, 82, 65, 38, 44, 71, 77, 64];
x = -180:30:179;

newX = -180:1:179; %Every degree
y_spline = interp1(x,y,-180:1:179,'spline');
y_pchip = interp1(x,y,-180:1:179,'pchip');

l(1) = plot(x,y,'Color',[0 0 1],'Marker','s');hold on
l(2) = plot(newX,y_spline,'r');
l(3) = plot(newX,y_pchip,'g');
grid on; legend(l,{'Orig','spline','pchip'});
```

[image: Plot Example]

Take your pick of interpolation methods ... or I could be completely misreading your question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  
I think I've figured it out now!